# How to create an HTTP redirect from a virtual directory using C#

Tags: c#, iis, redirect, directory, virtual

I can create an http redirect in my IIS by using the following code. However, it only creates a redirect for the main site "MySite" itself. How do I programatically add a redirect to a virtual directory? Is there some setting I need to set when I create the VD? Thanks!

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Configuration config = iisManager.GetWebConfiguration("MySite");
ConfigurationSection httpRedirectSection =  config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpRedirect");
httpRedirectSection["enabled"] = true;
httpRedirectSection["destination"] = @"http://www.google.com";
httpRedirectSection["exactDestination"] = false;
httpRedirectSection["httpResponseStatus"] = @"Found";

iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: I mean "from" a virtual directory. As in if the user goes to http://MySite/VD.aspx it redirects them to another page. I need to be able to add these through C#.

Answer (score 0):

Sean,

What your code is doing is essentially modifying the web.config file for your site.  The virtual directory is likely configured as an application so it would have its own web.config file.  Did you try doing the same thing but simply changing:

```
Configuration config = iisManager.GetWebConfiguration("MySite/VirtDirName");
```

Also, the virtual directory, since it is a child application may already be inheriting the httpRedirect setting from the parent site, I'd check first that this is not the case.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish with this without modifying the web config? Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, the code you're already using modifies the web.config.  Don't be afraid to modify it -- that is what it is there for, to provide you a way to configure the deployed application.  You can sort of do what you want differently but that also involves editing the web.config, I've done something similar to what you're doing by setting a customErrors page (in the web.config) for 404 errors to a 404.aspx page, then in the aspx page I look at the page that was actually requested and redirect accordingly.  Not sure if that is more what you're after or not.

Comment: The reason I want to be able to avoid modifying it is because I want to be able to create a VD and point it to a dummy directory that wont actually get used. In older versions of IIS you could set up a VD and check a box that says its a redirect. This didn't require modifying the web config. I'm trying to automate a process that creates VD's from a record set, I cant set up a new webconfig for each one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The newer versions of IIS appear to be shifting towards a heavier reliance on the web.config.  Some things that were in the metabase previously seem to have migrated to the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting it in IIS 7+ then you could use `web.config`.

Place a `web.config` in the directory and then add

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/[PathFromRoot]/" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Temporary" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can read up on the properties [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect)